# Interact with a python script within pexpect

Tags: python, pexpect

I am trying automate an interactive python script using pexpect. But it does not proceed after the control comes back to pexpect.

Here is a the mock up script try to simulate the same thing.

```
---------------- python script(script.py) -----------------
def issue_command():
        print "********** in issue_command ********"

def dummy_check():
        print "********** in dummy_check ********"
        raw_input("Now Press enter for next command")
        issue_command()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dummy_check()

--------------------------------Pexpect script(pexp.py)-----------------------
import pexpect
import sys

def quick_test():

        pobj = pexpect.spawn("/bin/bash")
        pobj.logfile = sys.stdout
        pobj.sendline("script.py")
        pobj.expect("Now Press enter for next command")
        print "\n1st part is done. Now execute the oil command"
        pobj.sendline()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    quick_test()
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I expect the output to be following.

```
$python pexp.py
********** in dummy_check ********
Now Press enter for next command  -------------------> It should wait here. Upon   pressing enter it should print the next line.
********** in issue_command ********
$
```

Instead, it does not print the 2nd line i.e. the pexpect could not interact
with the script after it returned in between.

```
$ python pexp.py
./script.py
********** in dummy_check ********
Now Press enter for next command -----> It ignored sendline() and did not execute issue_command function.
$
```

I have also tried passing the script(script.py) directly in the pexpect.spawn() instead of creating another shell(/bin/bash). It did not help.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can somebody please advise ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your pexpect is working correctly, but you haven't asked for more output from the spawn object yet.

Running the code you wrote as is, I get the following output:

```
********** in dummy_check ********
Now Press enter for next command
1st part is done. Now execute the oil command

$
```

If you add another `pobj.expect()` call to the end of `pexp.py`, you can get the remaining output. In particular, using the pexpect search constant `pexpect.EOF` will make your spawn object look for the end of the file (when the script completes) and log the output to stdout. Here is your code with the addition:

```python
import pexpect
import sys

def quick_test():
    pobj = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash')
    pobj.logfile = sys.stdout
    pobj.sendline('python script.py')
    pobj.expect("Now Press enter for next command")
    print "\n1st part is done. Now execute the oil command"
    pobj.sendline()
    pobj.expect(pexpect.EOF)  # <-- wait until we hit the end of the file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    quick_test()
```

Running this gives the following output:

```
********** in dummy_check ********
Now Press enter for next command
1st part is done. Now execute the oil command


********** in issue_command ********
$
```